# Bootstrap dropdown parent link not clickable

Tags: theming, navigation

This is the first drupal project i'm working on and i'm having the following problem.
I have my dropdown menu set up as followed:

[image: Dropdown menu with bootstrap]

The problem is that the parent link "Materialen" is not clickable while the children are.
What should i change to be able to click the parent link?

Comment: Why do you want make that as clickable? Do you want to give link to that parent-menu? Which module are you using for dropdown?

Comment: Yes i want to give a link to it. I just installed the drupal theme and added the taxonomy menu module. I want to make it clickable so the parent-menu can give an overall description.

Comment: Bootstrap decided it was better to have it behave like this for mobile/touch device users. Rollovers do not exist in mobile/touch devices so this was the solution. and since the majority of the web is going mobile, they were just future proofing. Duplicate the parent item underneath the drop-down with default bootstrap settings, or remove the functionality with the suggested answers but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 6):

A nice way that work with Drupal 8 would be to override in your subtheme:

```
menu--main.html.twig
```

And remove

```
 data-toggle="dropdown"
```

Cheers

Comment: There is no `data-toggle="dropdown"` in `menu--main.html.twig` in D8.

Comment: Adding to the above comment: This is a little confusing because the normal template override filename of `menu--main.html.twig` already exists in the bootstrap base theme and has other code in it.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove or comment out from your theme .info file this line:

```
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
```

It will automatically make navbar dropdown enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm late but I just discovered after mountains of readings if you take out line 33

```
 $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
```

of the menu-link.func.php should work

:)

Comment: You should not hack contributed code, instead create a subtheme and override the functions you need. For example, when the you update the theme you'll lost your changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Bootstrap theme (or a subtheme of it), you should be able to accomplish this with just some additional CSS.

This Bootply https://www.bootply.com/LcSwSskuR1 provides a nice solution, basically you need to add a :hover to the menu.  I believe this works with the Drupal Bootstrap theme:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .navbar-nav .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display:block;margin:0
  }
}
```

You may need to fiddle with the exact @media query you need for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Overide the menu.html.twig  and Remove that line
  {% set link_attributes = link_attributes.addClass('dropdown-toggle').setAttribute('data-toggle', 'dropdown') %}

with
  {% set link_attributes = link_attributes.addClass('dropdown-toggle').removeAttribute('data-toggle', 'dropdown') %}

i.e setAttribute('data-toggle', 'dropdown') to removeAttribute('data-toggle', 'dropdown')